# Unit Test async call in Task.WhenAll returns null (System.NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, task

I have a task inside a method that looks something like this:

```cs
public async Task<List<SomeType>> GetAnotherThing()
{
    var someTask = someList.Select(async anotherList => 
    {
        var someAsyncCall = await this.Provider.GetMeSomething()
        // More code here that uses the result
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(someTask);

    // more code here doing more stuff

}
```

Then I have a test method

```cs
public async Task BusinessLogic_GetAnotherThing()
{
    // bunch of code here
    WhateverType someExpectedResult= new WhateverType
    {
        // more data here
    };

    IProvider provider = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IProvider>();
    Provider
        .Expect(x => x.GetMeSomething())
        .Return(Task.FromResult(someExpectedResult));
}

SomeOtherType businessLogic = new SomeOtherType();
businessLogic.Provider = provider;

var actualGetAnotherThing = await businessLogic.GetAnotherThing();
// more code
}
```

When running the test method, I get the classic "System.NullReferenceException". It says that `var someAsyncCall = await this.Provider.GetMeSomething()` returned null.

Before I encapsulated this call in a Task where it was awaited in `Task.WhenAll`, everything was working fine in the unit test. I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Could you specify what framework for mocking are you using ? I suspect `.GetMeSomething()` returns `null` but normally mocking frameworks always return a `Task`

Comment: @EmyBlacksmith I'm using Rhino.Mocks. If I don't have the Task.WhenAll then it would just return what the mock is telling it to return, i.e. this: `
    Provider
        .Expect(x => x.GetMeSomething())
        .Return(Task.FromResult(someExpectedResult));`

But for some reason, it isn't. I think it's probably that it's no awaiting but I can't figure out how to do that in the test.

Comment: One thing that strikes me is that you set a mock on the property of the unit test class `Provider` but not the local variable `provider`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add "Repeat.Any()",

```
   IProvider provider = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IProvider>();
Provider
    .Expect(x => x.GetMeSomething())
    .Return(Task.FromResult(someExpectedResult)).Repeat.Any();
```